# Use interface or type for variable definition in java?

Tags: java

```
ArrayList aList = new ArrayList();

List aList = new ArrayList();
```

What's the difference between these two and which is better to use and why?

Comment: the correct answer, if there's such a thing, is the 1st form. see my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`List<T>` is interface, where `ArrayList<T>` is class, and this class implements `List<T>` interface.

I would prefer 2nd form, which is more general, ie if you do not use methods specific to `ArrayList<T>` you can declare its type as interface `List<T>` type. With 2nd form it will be easier to change  implementation from `ArrayList<T>` to other class that implements `List<T>` interface.

**EDIT:**
As many of SO users commented both forms can be arguments to any method that accept `List<T>` or `ArrrayList<T>`. But when I declare method I would prefer interface:

```
 void showAll(List <String> sl) ...
```

and use:

```
 void showAllAS(ArrayList <String> sl) ...
```

only when my method uses method specific to `ArrayList<T>`, like `ensureCapacity()`.

Response with information that we should use typed `List<T>` instead of just `List` is very good (of course if we do not use ancient Java).

Comment: This sounds worded backwards (wrong) to me.  The 1st form `ArrayList aList` can be passed as an argument to any method that takes a `List` or `ArrayList` parameter.  The 2nd form `List aList` can be passed as an argument to only methods that take a `List` parameter.  Although the variable `List aList` references an `ArrayList`, strong typing would prevent the reference variable `aList` from matching as an argument to an `ArrayList` parameter.

Comment: -1 It's exactly the other way around; you can pass an `ArrayList` to methods that want a `List`. You can't pass an `List` to a method asking for a `ArrayList`.

Comment: @Ishtar, Bert, exactly. But you forgot to mention that a method should almost never expect an ArrayList. In 99% of cases, any List and in 50% any Collection will do.

Comment: +1 I think Michal got a bit misunderstood here. If you create an interface, it's better to use a List if no ArrayList specific features are used inside. This way you do not impose an implementation upon the user. ArrayList is one of the possible implementations of a List.

Comment: @Roalt - I commented because I hope that Michał Niklas fixes his answer, so that it won't be misunderstood and it will be a good answer! But in its current state it *is* wrong.

Comment: @Roalt - I'm sure @Michal has it right in his head, but it came out wrong in the answer.  The initial notion is correct ("2nd form ... is more general"), but the rest is blatantly incorrect.  SO is a place for answers and correct information.  The downvotes and comments make sure the (accepted!) answer with incorrect information  isn't simply taken at face value.  The downvotes (and possibly comments) can be removed once the answer is corrected.

Comment: @Bert F: If he would have said "...you can pass a List (or ArrayList) to methods that operate on List parameter..." there would have been less confusion, right? I can see that it's now not right.

Comment: This is all very frustrating from my nine-upvotes point of view :P

Comment: I can imagine... remind me again why a single person gets to veto the entire community on which answer is best? I'm not against the possibility to accept answers, but the accepted answer doesn't have to be on top.

Comment: Thanks for comments. You are right I was thinking more about declaring method, not variables. I hope my edited answer is better.

Answer (score 22):

List is an Interface, whereas ArrayList is an implementation of that interface.

The second is better because it means you can change your ArrayList for another implementation of List later without needing to change the rest of your application. You may want to do this for performance reasons, or because of other aspects of the behaviour of the List implementation that you have chosen/will choose.

Comment: Exactly. If you ever find you need to ensure you are working with an ArrayList later, you can change the declaration then. Otherwise, the rest of your code really doesn't need to know what kind of List is being used, so that you can swap for a different implementation later (perhaps LinkedList) if performance or other considerations warrant it.

Comment: @Bill everyone always mentions LinkedList at the implementation you might switch too, but I think the case gets stronger if you mention Collections.unmodifiableList(), Collections.checkedList(), or Collections.synchronizedList().

Comment: @ILMTitan not to mention other collections like the Immutable ones from Google Collections.

Comment: +1 Cut and dry. Researching topic and wish I had found this earlier because these words answered more questions than a thousand bloated, repetitive essays on the subject. </poeticlicense>

Answer (score 7):

Both are deprecated since Java 1.5.

It should be:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
// or whatever data type you are using in your list
```

Please read [Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/) by Joshua Bloch, especially these two items:

- 23: Don't use raw types in new code (this is even [available online](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/generics.pdf))
- 52: Refer to objects by their
  interfaces

BTW, if you use [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries), you have [a factory method](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#newArrayList%28%29) for constructing an ArrayList so you don't have to repeat the type parameter:

```
List<String> list = Lists.newArraylist();
```

Comment: I hope everyone knows that you should use the template-version of List by now (e.g. eclipse will nag you about it if you don't). But your 2nd remark about Guava is quite interesting!

Comment: @dertoni I agree, it's the only *one* book that every java developer should read.

Comment: I'd say it's the *first* book every Java developer should read ;)

Comment: The links to Effective Java are broken

Answer (score 2):

All these answers are the same recite from some dogma they read somewhere.

A variable declaration and initialization statement, `Type x = new Constructor();`, is definitely part of implementation detail. It's not part of a public API (unless it's `public final`, but `List` is mutable so that's inappropriate)

As an implementation detail, who you are trying to fool with your abstractions? It's better to keep the type as specific as possible. Is it an array list or a linked list? Should it be thread safe or not? The choice is important for your implementation, you carefully chose the specific list impl. Then you declare it as a mere `List` as if it doesn't matter and you don't care?

The only legitimate reason to declare it as `List` is *I'm too lazy to type*. That also covers the argument that *if I need to move to another List impl I have one less place to modify*.

This reason is legitimate only when the variable scope is small, and you can see all of its usages from one glance. Otherwise, keep the most specific type, so that its performance and semantic characteristics are manifest across all the code that use the variable.

Comment: I mostly disagree with this, but it doesn't deserve -3; upvoting because it raises valid arguments (even though I disagree with the conclusion).

Comment: BTW, one point where I disagree is "The choice is important for your implementation, you carefully chose the specific list impl" If that is the case, using the concrete type might be justified, but in my experience, it often is not the case. When e.g. using collection classes, I almost always just use ArrayList & HashSet, and only reconsider if that causes problems (i.e. practically never). In that case using List/Set better expresses my *intention*, i.e. "I just want a list".

Comment: +1; I fully agree on that. If the scope is small then use the specific type. I was tossed here from your other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12805778/1350762

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the second in most cases because it signifies that you're not using anything specific in the ArrayList api, and if you need to later you can substitute any other type of List without having to change any code except the first line.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Java quirk, due to limited type inference and doctrine OOP. For local variables it's mostly style; if you need some specific feature of the subtype, use the subtype (examples below), but otherwise fine to use either.

Java style is to use the supertype, to enforce interfaces even within the body of implementations, and for consistency with visible types (*Effective Java* 2nd Edition: Item 52: Refer to objects by their interfaces). In languages with more type inference, such as C++/C#/Go/etc., you don't need to explicitly state the type, and the local variable will have the *specific* type.

For visible types (public or protected: fields, or parameters and return value of methods), you almost always want to use the most general type: interface or abstract class, to provide better flexibility (*Effective Java*: Item 40: Design method signatures carefully). However, for types that are not visible (private or package-private members, or local variables), it's ok to use either (it's just style) and sometimes necessary to use more specific types, including concrete classes.

See *Effective Java* for standard guidelines; personal thoughts follow.

The reason to use more general types even if not visible is to reduce noise: you're stating that you only need the more general type. Using general types on members that are not visible (like private methods) also reduces churn if you ever change types. However, this doesn't apply to local variables, where it's just changing one line anyway: `ConcreteFoo foo = new ConcreteFoo();` to `OtherConcreteFoo foo = new OtherConcreteFoo();`.

Cases where you *do* need the subtype include:

- You need members only present on the subtype, e.g.:

  - some feature of the implementation, like `ensureCapacity` for `ArrayList<T>`
  - *(common in test code)*  some member of a fake class, like (hypothetically) `FakeFileSystem#createFakeFile`.
- You rely on the behavior of the subtype, notably in overrides of the supertype's methods, like:

  - having a more general type of parameter,
  - more specific return type, or
  - throwing a more specific or fewer exception types.

As an example of the last, see [Should I close a StringReader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122013/should-i-close-a-stringreader): [StringReader.html#close](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html#close()) overrides [Reader.html#close](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#close()) and does *not* throw an `IOException`, so using `StringReader` instead of `Reader` for the local variable means you don't need to handle an exception that can't actually occur, and significantly reduces boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 1.4 or earlier, then I would use the second one. It's always better to declare your fields as generically as possible, in case you need to make it into something else later on, like a Vector, etc.

Since 1.5 I would go with the following

```
List<String> x = new ArrayList<String>();
```

It gives you a little bit of type safety. List 'x' can add a String Object, and that's it. When you get an item from the List 'x', you can count on the fact that a String is going to come back. This also helps by removing unnecessary casting, which can make code hard to read when you go back 6 months later and try to remember what your code does. Your compiler/IDE will help you to remember what type should be going in to List 'x' by displaying an error if you try to add any other Object type.

If you want to add multiple Object types to a List then you could add an Annotation to suppress the compile error

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List y = new ArrayList();
```

Comment: This is bad style. Don't suppress warnings, use `List<Object>`. Example: `List<Object> y = new ArrayList<Object>(); y.add(1); y.add("abc"); y.add(true);`

Comment: (The auto-boxing I used in my example is also bad style, of course)

Comment: If you're using 1.4 or earlier the first thing to do is to upgraded your JVM.

Comment: I don't want to start a flame war, I just want to give justification for leaving the Java 1.4 reference. I'm sure there is at least one other poor developer out there that has no choice but to use less than the most current tools when maintaining an old product. It's an unfortunate fact that some of us have no recourse but to continue to use an old JVM on large legacy projects because the business will only allow updates to custom code, but not to supporting libraries. There is also the justification of the cost of retesting an entire code base that could cause an old JVM to be used.

Answer (score 0):

I know of at least one case when declaring a variable with an interface does not work.  When you want to use reflection.

I made a bug fix on some code where I declared a variable as `Map<String, MyObject>` and assigned it an instance of `HashMap<String, MyObject>`.  This variable was used as a parameter in a method call that was accessed via reflection.  The problem is that reflection tried to find a method with `HashMap` signature and not the declared `Map` signature.  Since there was no method with a `HashMap` as a parameter I was unable to find a method by reflection.

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

public void test(Map<String, Object> m) {...};

Method m = this.getClass().getMethod("test", new Class<?>[]{map.getClass()});
```

Will **not** find the method that uses the interface.  If you make another version of test that uses `HashMap` instead then it will work - but now you are forced to declare your variable with a concrete class and not the more flexible interface...

Comment: the bug is the in the method lookup code. a sophisticated lookup will not require exact parameter type match, instead, it simulates compiler's algorithm to find a suitable method.

Comment: The actual bug here is you are using map.getClass(), which will return HashMap.class, for the method lookup, while you should use Map.class instead.

Comment: @John seems like a small typo but it is more than that.  The whole purpose behind using reflection in this particular case is that I DON'T know which method to call.  I am passed a List<Object> for the parameters.  If I knew that I wanted to use the method with the Map<> parameter I wouldn't be using reflection :)

Comment: Still, Java should not be confused with Java-with-reflection.