# Creating object using Abstract class or interface reference

Tags: java, oop

Why is this a good practice to create objects using references in the upper level in inheritance hierarchy in object oriented programming, as I keep coming across this tendency in most professionally written codes.

e.g

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Comment: Interfaces define a common contract to which implementations are expected to adhere to without exposing the underlying implementation, this makes it flexible to the use the API with (generally) adversely constricting your choices (think arrays, `Vector` and `List`).  Abstract classes reduce the amount of repeat work which is generally required just to get the interface up and running and generally focus on filling out those methods whose functionality is likely to be commonly re-used - in short - we're lazy and don't want keep writing the same code over and over again

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of code? Do you really mean references?

Comment: Are you referring to the construct `List<X> list = new ArrayList<X>()`, meaning the use of the interface on the left, instead of the concrete class?

Comment: the old `List list = new ArrayList()` question; of which the consensus opinion is wrong :)

Comment: yes @Andreas , that's one exact example of my concern

Comment: It's better to use the most specific type possible for a local variable.

Comment: @bayou.io You have any reference for that statement. Both that there is a consensus (what is it?) and that it is wrong (says who and why?).

Comment: @Andreas - the consensus is "program against interface", it's wrong because that adage applies to APIs, not implementations. This line of code is definitely implementation detail, and it's better to be as precise as possible.

Comment: One reason I can think of is that it is shorter, e.g. the longest List implementation is called `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, so `List<X> list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<X>()` is nicer than `CopyOnWriteArrayList<X> list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<X>()`, if you don't need any concrete method that's not in the interface.

Comment: @bayou.io So far that's your opinion stated there. I was asking if you had any references (links) to go with that. I'm not saying you're right or wrong, I'm just asking for references.

Comment: @bayou.io I'm with Andreas, if you claim that "It's better to use the most specific type possible for a local variable" - the least you should do is provide some reasoning to go along with it (but references will be even better!).

Comment: @Andreas - My opinion is not good enough? :)

Comment: @alfasin - how about this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/3774026/2158288

Comment: @bayou.io that's a weak reasoning. Some of it is simply not true: "that its **performance** and semantic characteristics are manifest across all the code...". Do you also believe that it affects performance ?

Comment: @alfasin - the performance characteristics of an ArrayList is more clear than a List. If a class implementation contains a list, and the implementer chose to use ArrayList, there must be a good reason for that; it's better to declare the instance variable as `ArrayList`, not just arbitrary `List`

Comment: @alfasin It's very right on that point, actually. If you use `get(index)`, then it matter whether the list is an `ArrayList` or a `LinkedList`, because the performance is *very* different. If all you do is add and iterate, then it doesn't matter and using `List` is fine, but if you intend to use `get()`, you should declare it as `ArrayList` to say it matters.

Comment: I respectfully disagree: hiding implementation details is one of the corner-stones of OO. You don't hide implementation detail only if you have a good reason not to do it - but it shouldn't be the default. By exposing which class you have chosen you will not be able to change it in the future without breaking client-code. As for that specific example you seem to have missed my point - performance *will* be the same regardless if you declare the reference as a `List` or as an `ArrayList`.

Comment: @alfasin You missed 2 points: 1) It's arguing that specifying the concrete class allows the following code to *know* the characteristics of the implementation, such as performance (is using `get()` a good idea) and concurrency (it is safe to multi-thread). --- 2) It won't break client code, because this discussion is about the declaration of a *variable* and only affects the current method, not any clients, and is therefore not the same argument/context most used when discussing "program to interface".

Comment: @tural Sorry for hijacking your question for this discussion. I hope the "duplicate" link I provided will help you find the answer you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas, yes, some of the answers gave me an idea in duplicate link. That was helpful

Comment: @Andreas Based on what you guys decided that this code is only "local" and won't affect client code? I don't see any mentions to it in the question... The only good reasons I see to not using an interface are: 1. if such an interface doesn't exist. 2. If we need to use a method which is specific to an implementation of the interface. Even if we'll assume that  the use is only "local" - then since you already know which implementation was chosen - you don't really have to specify it, right ? :)

Comment: @alfasin Based on the fact that it's declaring a *variable*, not a return value, a parameter, or a field.

Comment: Readers of the code will have a better understanding of what's going on with the implementation, if the code provides more detailed type information. Actually, that is the main point of static typing - it is for the benefit of the programmers to see which is what. (the other camp argues that variable names and contexts are enough to understand the code)

Comment: @Andreas How can you tell that it will not be used as a return value ?

Comment: @alfasin The value could, for sure, but the *return type* may be different from the *variable type*, and we're discussing the variable here.

Comment: @Andreas sorry but I didn't understand your last comment...

Comment: @alfasin `List<X> myMethod() { ArrayList<X> list = new ArrayList<X>(); /* code that uses list, knowing that get() is good to use */; return list; }` --- Implementation code is using explicit knowledge, returned value is using API, i.e. "programming to interface". --- Should variable `list` be `List` or `ArrayList`? Arguments both ways depending on use *within* method. Client not affected either way.

Comment: @tural - In practice, this is not a big deal either way -- don't argue with your colleague in real life :)

Comment: @Andreas oh now I see what you meant. In that case I don't see any added value for one approach vs. the other.

Comment: @bayou.io Although I ended up arguing the point you made early on, I'll stick with my early comment of using interface for conciseness (not lazyness, oh no), unless having a overriding reason not to.  ;-)

Comment: Yeah, better to develop *good* habits, and break them only if there's a good reason to do so.

Comment: @Andreas - So why List, but not Collection? For conciseness, or laziness? :) My own practice is to always use the bottom type, not any one of the super types (there could be many). This is easier to practice than choosing a proper supertype:)